# WiFi hotspot is not working on debian

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian, android

I have ASUS nettop with WiFi adapter and want to use it as hotspot.

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: ****
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-4-amd64 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff

Available Antennas: TX 0x1 RX 0x3
Configured Antennas: TX 0x1 RX 0x3
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * WDS
     * monitor
     * mesh point
     * P2P-client
     * P2P-GO
```

Adapter seems to be loaded successfully, but I can't see it among wifi hotspots from my Android mobile phone

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

eth1      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I have set up hostapd as described [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-setting-wireless-access-point/) but without bridged connection because I don't need it right now.

What could possible be the reason my hotspot can't be actually discovered?

UPD:
I've listed hostapd errors while start, but still don't know what does that mean, what's exactly the problem with driver:

```
sudo hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=2 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: TDLS external setup
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x7f5679770d80
nl80211: Register frame type=0xb0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_AUTH) nl_handle=0x7f5679770d80 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0x0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ASSOC_REQ) nl_handle=0x7f5679770d80 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0x20 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_REASSOC_REQ) nl_handle=0x7f5679770d80 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0xa0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DISASSOC) nl_handle=0x7f5679770d80 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0xc0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DEAUTH) nl_handle=0x7f5679770d80 match=
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x7f5679770d80 match=
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=3)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Teardown AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x7f56797703c0)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x7f56797703c0)
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan0
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x7f5679771700 (wlan0))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=(nil) drv_priv=(nil) -> hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0x7f56797703c0)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x7f5679771700
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x7f56797703c0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x7f56797703c0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x7f56797703c0
```

Comment: Your wireless chipset might not be capable of providing a hosted/access point network mode so your efforts might be in vein...

Comment: @big Bloody good remark.

Comment: this is working for men. does not require it reboot
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339087/unable-to-create-hotspot-using-network-manager-of-gnome-arch-linux/349358#answer-349358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was in hostapd.conf, maybe it will help someone:

I used hostapd.conf settings from this [post](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-setting-wireless-access-point/) while it seems to be wrong or deprecated,
 after I looked through Hostapd Howto [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hostapd) I've noticed that there is another way to specify driver for hostapd, I **replaced driver=nl80211 with ieee80211n=1 in hostapd.conf** and hotspot started working.